# Splunk configuration of inputs.conf at application level via chef role

Tags: chef-infra, splunk

I have Splunk set up for two or more applications and I have created separate roles in chef for each app and running it on app servers to configure Splunk (configurations are in chef roles file)

However, the requirement is to run more than one app on same server; and as per current chef cookbook and roles it will override the inputs.conf file when I run a second role on the server. Is there a way to create an app specific inputs.conf file like app1.conf, app2.conf (instead of inputs.conf) or a way to append into the inputs.conf file via chef with multiple roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in Splunk, you have to use inputs.conf to configure inputs.
You can use several inputs.conf files simultaneously in the following manner:

```
system/local/inputs.conf 
App1/local/inputs.conf
App2/local/inputs.conf
```

Splunk will merge them and use all their configurations together.
If there is any conflict, system overrides apps, apps overrides each other lexicography, apps overrides users, and so on.

Source: http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.1/Admin/Wheretofindtheconfigurationfiles

Comment: Hi, It didn't work for me. Splunk is not recognizing the different inputs isn App folders.

Comment: Hi,
You can run btool to see what splunk actually found out in the files:

bin/splunk btool inputs list --debug